# Unable to show complete response from webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services

Has anyone met this situation so far?

Right now im consuming one webservice in android.Its is returning its response in json format but the size of that response is more than 3mb i think so,by then i can only able  to see half of the Response data from that service.
Can anyone tell me how see all response data from that service?

Suggestion please

Thanks for your precious time!..

```
private void Calling_Webservice() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    String URL      =   "";
    String METHOD_NAME  =   "";
    String NAMESPACE    =   "";
    String SOAPACTION   =   "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("","");

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL,15000);
    try {

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAPACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();


    /* Checking response */

        if (result != null) {
            InputStream in = httpTransportSE.getEntity().getContent(result); 

            // Get the data in the entity

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String result_data =  new String();
            while ((result_data = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
                System.out.println("RESPONSE IS     :   " + result_data);
            }

        }}

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do "think" you can only see half of the response ? (your logcat is truncated ?) Please be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take one Scrollview and add Textview to scroll view then
first get all response in string variable and in on postexecute textview.settext(yourresponse). thats it then you can show all response data.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working pretty well for me, try this -

```
public static void longInfo(String str) {
        if(str.length() > 4000) {
            Log.i(str.substring(0, 4000));
            longInfo(str.substring(4000));
        } else
            Log.i(str);
    }
```